# Need suggestion on how can i start implementing the attached UI

Tags: carousel

I am new to building UIs, as a part of a project i was asked to come up with a UI (screenshot attached). Before posting it here, i have done my research and could not find a solution.

Please look at the attached screenshot, and need your suggestion on how can i achieve it, or, suggest any site which has UI similar to attached UI design.[image].

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a 3D carousel, a component for cycling through elements.

I found this [intro to CSS 3D transforms](https://desandro.github.io/3dtransforms/), there is not exactly what you need, but working on the angles of rotation I think you can achive your concept.